# Typescript type object nested path string

Tags: typescript

I have the following `get` function:

```js
function get<T>(obj: T, props: (keyof T)[] | keyof T): any {
  const toArray = coereceArray(props);
  return obj && toArray.reduce(
    (result, prop) => result == null ? undefined : result[prop] as any,
    obj
  );
}

const result = get({ a: { b: 'hey' } }, ['a', 'b']);
const result2 = get({ a: { b: 'hey' } }, 'a');
```

How can I type the result dynamically based on the passed params?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very interesting case. To perform gathering of all keys also from nested objects we need to do recursion, fortunately recursive types are available in the TS. But if we do so we have additional issue, and exactly - `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite` as for this exact case we cannot say how deep the object can be, check this issue to understand about what I am talking about - [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31619)

In order to perform our gathering we need to put there a limit of recursion. I put the limit as 5, you can extend it by repeating the pattern.

Firstly the type:

```
type Level = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 'max'; // this solves the infinite loop error issue
type NextLevel<Level> =
    Level extends 0 ? 1
    : Level extends 1 ? 2
    : Level extends 2 ? 3
    : Level extends 3 ? 4
    : Level extends 4 ? 5
    : 'max'; // this type enables iterating from 0 to 5, with the end as 'max'

type NestedKeyof<T, L extends Level = 0> = L extends 'max' ? never : {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? K | NestedKeyof<T[K], NextLevel<L>> : K
}[keyof T]
```

`NestedKeyof` type is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) which gathers all keys in the map, but if the value in the key is an object then it will perform gathering for this object also. The important think is `K | NestedKeyof<T[K], NextLevel<L>>` so we recursively pass the object `T[K]` and we iterate the level by `NextLevel<L>`. The iteration is finished with `max` type, what is visible on the beginning of the type - `L extends 'max' ? never`.

Simple test of the type shows correct results:

```
type NestedType = NestedKeyof<{ a: { b: 'hey', c: { d: 'elo' } } }>; // a | b | c | d
```

Now how to use it with your function:

```
function get<T, P extends NestedKeyof<T>>(obj: T, props: P[] | keyof T): any {
  const toArray = coereceArray(props);
  return obj && toArray.reduce(
    (result, prop) => result == null ? undefined : result[prop] as any,
    obj
  );
}

const result = get({ a: { b: 'hey' } }, ['a', 'b']); // correct
const result2 = get({ a: { b: 'hey' } }, 'a');  // correct
const result3 = get({ a: { b: 'hey' } }, ['a', 'b', 'c']); // error as expected
```

---

`NestedKeyof` type has limitation, as I created `Level` and `NextLevel` for max 5 levels of nested object. For example such type:

```
type NestedTypeAboveMax = NestedKeyof
<{ a: { b: 'hey', c: { d: 'elo', e: { f: { g: { h: {i: 'test'}} } } } } }>;
```

Will not take key `i` as it is out of the limit. However if such nested structures will be used, then you can extend `Level` and `NextLevel` to be capable to have more levels.